# Open source LaunchBox C#/.NET

Tags: c#, .net, launcher

I need to develop a LaunchBox (see the footnote) for a series of small games I wrote in Unity 3D. I'm going to develop it from scratch with my little hands, but before starting I would like to know if anyone knows an open source project so as to avoid wasting precious time. Preferably a project set to C#.NET.

---

Footnote: For LaunchBox I mean a program that collects in its GUI the list (or set) of the games that I have developed, in this way the user starts the LaunchBox and then can choose one of the games available. Something vaguely similar to what Netflix and Steam do, but really simple, without division into categories and other things. Some examples in the images I've linked.

[Example 1](https://forums.launchbox-app.com/uploads/monthly_2017_01/58712f406e7db_2017-01-0713_10_45-LaunchBoxPremium-LicensedtoScottSmith.jpg.e99eef7f6fb755c2754384200a239ed3.jpg)
[Example 2](https://betanews.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/LaunchBox.jpg)
and so on...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[PlayNite](https://playnite.link/) is an open source game launcher in the same vein as LaunchBox capable of creating organizing and managing your game library. It is portable, may be used without formal installation on the host system, and run from an external drive or USB stick.

It can integrate with and launch games from popular third party platforms like Steam, Origin, Uplay, GOG, among others.

It can also integrate with a variety of emulators and frontend launchers for other systems, listing games from their integrated libraries.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Very cool, there is also a well-kept GitHub repository. Just what I needed, thank you very much for reporting!